# How to convert csv to xls using R?

Tags: r, csv, xls

I have a folder with few hundred CSV files. What would be the easiest way to convert these to XLS format using R?

(Yes, I know CSV is Excel-compatible but I still have good reason to convert them.)

Comment: Use the package `XLConnect`

Comment: Additionally, you can try `xlsx`, `xlsReadWrite`, `RExcelXML`, `datafram2xls` and `WriteXLS`. See http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-data.html#Reading-Excel-spreadsheets

Comment: We're dying to know:  what's the "good reason" ? Other than binding csv files into a single Excel workbook, I couldn't think of one.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Usually, the answer to that question is "co-workers or colleagues who insist upon it".

Comment: @Joran You're right, the "good reason" is not so much a technical one - the files will be published and should be XLS for historic consistency..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the package `xlsReadWrite` to export to xls:

```
library(xlsReadWrite)
filenames <- list.files("[path_name]", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)
for(i in 1:length(filenames)){
    a <- read.csv(filenames[i])
    write.xls(a, paste("file",i,".xls", sep=""))
}
```

Comment: Downvoting because this answer consists solely of external links.  This should have been a comment, not an answer. If you expand this to an answer with R code, I might change my mind.

Comment: Yeah, this appears not to work. `Error in .Call("WriteXls", x, file, colNames, sheet, from - 1, rowNames,  : 
  Incorrect number of arguments (7), expecting 6 for 'WriteXls'`