# Converting CSV files to Excel in R

Tags: r

The question I have is similar to this one [CSV to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068915/how-to-convert-csv-to-xls-using-r)

However by using the code mentioned in that post, the file name changes to file followed by the sequence number that the file happened to be in. My question is how do we retain the file name? 
Like now we get file1.xlsx, file2.xlsx, etc.. I want to be able to get 
analysis report.xlsx , budgeting.xlsx. Any suggestions ?

Here is the code that I am using

```
 filenames <- list.files("D:/finished CSVs", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)

for(i in 1:length(filenames))
{
  a<- read.csv(filenames[i])
  write.xlsx(a,paste("file",i,".xlsx", sep=""))
}
```

Comment: Show the code you are using and we can help you modify it.

Comment: Code added to the original post. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to iterate over names on this occasion:

```
filenames <- list.files("D:/finished CSVs", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)

for(i in filenames) {
  a <- read.csv(i)
  new_name <- sub('.csv', '.xlsx', i, fixed = TRUE)
  write.xlsx(a, new_name)
}
```

Comment: Sometimes I make things much more difficult than they really are :P. Thanks @Gregor

Comment: It works. Thank you. Only one problem though, I get rownumber in the first column of the xlsx files. Like when I open the xlsx file , Column A has numbers, which are row numbers from R I guess?

Comment: You are welcome :). Use `write.xlsx(a, new_name, row.names = FALSE)`

Comment: @LyzanderR I was just going to reply that I figured it out. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Filename from a path can be retrieved with `basename()`. Something like this should work

```r
convert_csv_to_xlsx <- function(csv_path, xlsx_dir_path = "D:/finished_xslx") {
  csv_name <- basename(xlsx_path)
  xlsx_name <- sub(pattern = "csv$", replacement = "xlsx", x = xlsx_name)
  xlsx_path <- file.path(xlsx_dir_path, xlsx_name)
  db <- read.csv(csv_path)
  write.xslx(db, xlsx_path)
} 

filenames <- list.files("D:/finished CSVs", pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)

lapply(filenames, convert_csv_to_xlsx)
```

Comment: @Gregor and jomuller thanks for replying. The previous answer worked. That was exactly what I wanted the code to do.